# Why IDA Pro can not generate this subroutine's code?

Tags: ida

I use IDA Pro 6.1 to disassemble static linked binary on Windows 32bit

See, in the interactive screen, this subroutine (which is in one library function) can be found:

[image: IDAPro asm display]

But as I use these two ways to generate asm code:

1. File->Produce->Create ASM File
2. IDC script to iterate all the functions

In both ways I can find this library function, but I can not find the definition of the subroutine `$LN28_0`. Which means in the generated asm code, all the `jmp $LN28_0` is undefined.

So, I am wondering if it is a bug of IDA Pro? Or, do I need to configure some things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that $LN28_0 is local label, not subroutine.
Find it, rename it manually, regenerate the file.